# How to create wordpress install template/image?

Tags: installation

I'm looking to create a wordpress install image/package/template, not sure how it would be called.
Basically I want to set a certain plugins, translations, settings and make a template of that wordpress and be able to install it with fewer clicks on another host.
Two ways I know of:

WP All Import plugin, to just set up one wordpress site and export it. Problem with this method is that it will always install outdated plugins + I'm not sure if this is the cleanest method.

Second way: (I usually install WP on linux servers) is to use bash script and wp-cli to install all sorts of things, but I'm that seems tedious to do since there's a lot of stuff I want to change and do it all through bash script would require lots of code.

Does anyone know another good way to make a wordpress "template" install? Thanks.